# Leverage Browser Cache asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, iis-7.5, browser-cache

I tried to check the speed of my website using

https://developers.google.com/speed/

It says to Leverage Browser Cache.
I tried doing this by placing the following code in `web.config` file

```
<staticContent>
<clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" httpExpires="Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT" />
</staticContent>
```

And I rechecked again. But it is showing the same again!

Does the above code sole the problem actually??
I'm using `IIS 7.5` and `.NET Framework 4.0` for my website.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes any difference but I got it working with UTC time format:

```
<staticContent>
  <clientCache httpExpires="Sun, 26 Oct 2014 00:00:00 UTC" cacheControlMode="UseExpires" />
</staticContent>
```